# This line of code is giving me the wrong dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

`mat = np.squeeze( np.mean(vec[i0-5:i0+5, :], axis=0))`

This is yielding me dimensions of (145,) and I need it to be (145,1). I know this is a simple fix but cant figure out where to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague on how your variables look. I'm making the following assumptions:

```py
vec = np.random.uniform(size=(145,145))
i0 = 10
```

To make the array 2 dimensional, reshape the array.

```py
new_mat = np.reshape(mat, (-1, 1))
```

Here `-1` infers the dimension from your `mat` array.